# Angular Material 2 cards with flex-layout overlap eachother

Tags: angular, angular-material2, angular-flex-layout

I'm trying to get the Angular Material 2 cards to work using flex-layout, so that as the browser is resized the number of columns i'm rendering changes. I'm trying to achieve something similar to how [Google Keep](https://keep.google.com/) works.

```
<div *ngIf="condition == true">
    <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutWrap="wrap" fxLayoutAlign="start start" fxLayoutGap="15px" >
        <md-card fxFlex="calc(25%+15px)" *ngFor="let d of details">
            <md-card-content>
                Content
            </md-card-content>
        </md-card>
    </div>
</div>    
<button md-button (click)="condition = !condition">Toggle</button>
```

Running [this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/xTTkYjQaa4hJxhqSn7AA?p=preview) though, you can see that when ever a series of Angular Material cards need to wrap, they overlap a little bit.

Does anyone know what I would need to do with flex-layout in order to get the next row to have some margin between the items? They have the `fxLayoutGap` attribute, but that seems to only work on gutters between the objects immediately adjacent to the content and not beneath or above.

Answer (score 2):

Johnathon, I feel your pain. Even without using flex-layout, I have struggled to get md-cards to behave completely as I want them to - but I will say it can be done, but often to the detriment of maintainability and time efficiency.

I have not implemented flex-layout for any of my own purposes, as I have used the flex approach for some time in core CSS.

This is not a plug for my site, but it *is* the best example I can have you look at: http://www.weo3.com - you'll see on the landing page, the "work" section is made up of cards. These cards are *based on* Material Design's approach, but are stripped down to the layout essence that I wanted.

Here is the CSS I have used to accomplish their spacing, and their responsiveness - and please note that "work" is the parent container for the cards!

```
.work {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 10px;
}

.card .card-content {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 0.25em 0.3em 0;
}

.card .card-content p {
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 1.2;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}


@media only screen and (min-width: 37.50em) {
  .card {
    max-width: calc(50% - 20px);
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 75em) {
  .card {
    width: calc(33.33333% - 20px);
  }
}
```

Hopefully, as you can see, one of the main mechanics that assist in the cards keeping their space is the width calculations that directly correlate with the margin declaration. So, if you want margins of 10px on each side of a card, then the width needs to calculate the percentage of the screen you want the card to take, minus the margin amount *times two*.

FWIW, what I have found using MaterialDesign2 is to either be completely happy with its behavior, or minimize its impact, in order to enjoy it.

MaterialDesign2 is still in beta, so as you move forward with codebases such as this, remember that adjustments may have to be made to maintain the integrity of your designs, as those codebases grow and mature.